# Play framework Application Hosting

Tags: scala, playframework, web-hosting

I`m working on a web application which is developed using scala and play frame work. Now I need to host it for the testing. Anyone has some suggestions **free hosting** service which support **play frame work and scala** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try Heroku - they have some good basic free packages and Play framework support:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play-support